# Passing build parameters downstream using groovy. Jenkins build pipeline

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I've seen a number of examples that execute a pre build system groovy script to the effect of

```
import hudson.model.*
def thr = Thread.currentThread()
def build = thr?.executable
printf "Setting SVN_UPSTREAM as "+ build.getEnvVars()['SVN_REVISION']  +"\n" ; 
build.addAction(new ParametersAction(new StringParameterValue('SVN_UPSTREAM', build.getEnvVars()['SVN_REVISION'])))
```

Which is intended to make `SVN_UPSTREAM` available to all downstream jobs.

With this in mind I attempt to use `$SVN_UPSTREAM` in a manually executed downstream job like

```
https://code.mikeyp.com/svn/mikeyp/client/trunk@$SVN_UPSTREAM
```

Which is not resolved causing an error.

Can anyone spot the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bleeding edge jenkins build pipeline plugin now supports parameter passing. Eliminated the need for the groovy workaround for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the parameter you are passing downstream is *not* set as a parameter in the downstream job where you wish to use it. That is, in the downstream job, if you have "This build is parametrized" checked, do not add SVN_UPSTREAM to the list of parameters. If you do, it overrides the preset value.